# Kill a process from Linux Application

Tags: linux, grep, kill, ps

What is best and most efficient way to find pid of a specific task. Say:

```
ps -ef | grep "\/usr\/sbin\/watchdog" | cut -d" " -f2
```

Is there any more efficient way to find the same. I want to kill the watchdog process from my application. I am thinking using system command to do the same.

```
system("kill -9 `ps -ef | grep "\/usr\/sbin\/watchdog" | cut -d" " -f2`);
```

Is there any more optimized way of doing the same.

Comment: You should only use -9 as a last resort, not routinely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `pidof`

```
kill -9 `pidof <your application name>`
```

your application name could be /usr/sbin/watchdog

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is an ideal world solution...

To get the watchdog PID, you only need to open the file `'/var/run/watchdog.pid'`.

Once you know the PID of a process, the best way to kill the process is not to call the `'system'` function, but to call the `'kill'` function of the UNIX API:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int
kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```

This avoids spawning new processes.

If the file `'/var/run/watchdog.pid'` does not exist, you can revert to system/kill/pidof.

Answer (score 1):

To display all processes owned by the current user type ps ux and hit return:

```
$ ps ux
USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
jhaas 3064 0.1 3.6 18324 9088 ? S 17:55 0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-session
jhaas 3107 0.0 0.3 3128 968 ? S 17:55 0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xinit/Xclients
....
```

Now, if you want to terminate for example the emacs process you would look up the process identifier (PID) in the above table (3216), and say:

```
$ kill -9 3216
```

Source: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_kill.htm

Comment: There is a `c` tag, meaning this should be a C solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over the subdirectories in `/proc`, finding the processes you want to kill. Then use `kill(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on: http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc

You can search `/proc` file system and find a link `/proc/$(PIC)/exe` that points to `/usr/sbin/watchdog`

Once you get pid just `kill` it (see man 2 kill)

Comment: proc file system lists the process Ids, how can I find the process Id of specific application(say watchdog) from there.

Comment: @Karun: use pidof , you can checkout my answer

Comment: @Karun: for each process there is a directory named after the PID. In this directory you'll find the information you're looking for (as described in the linked man-page).

Answer (score 0):

`pgrep` is actually quite nice for this, especially if you ever intend to use a regular expression to match against process names. It is part of the [`procps`](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) package, which should already be installed on any linux system (`ps` is in the same package).
Here's an example usage:

```
psychotic@bismuth ~ $ pgrep 'fire.*'
2902
2903
2904
6979
psychotic@bismuth ~ $ pgrep -l 'fire.*'
2902 firegl
2903 firegl
2904 firegl
6979 firefox-bin
```